# How to pre-process a video stream used in an HTML 5 VIDEO tag?

Tags: html5-video

Let's say I have an MP4 file on a remote server that's encrypted (i. e. is in some format that cannot be immediately used as the src in an HTML 5 VIDEO tag).

I want JavaScript code that will be able to fetch that file, decrypt it (assuming I have the JavaScript code to do so), and then have it play using the VIDEO tag, WHILE the file is being decrypted (i. e. as opposed to reading the whole file into an array, processing it, and then creating a blob URL for it that's later assigned as the src to the VIDEO tag).

The problem is that the HTML 5 VIDEO tag only accepts a filename or blob URL as the SRC.  So my question, essentially, is if there's anyway I can specify a stream URL to be the VIDEO src, and then access that stream (i. e. via an Event) and then within that event, add data to that stream incrementally.

I've researched the JavaScript MediaStream API, but don't see anyway I can use it to add processed data (i. e. a portion of a decoded stream) to the stream as described above.

If this CANNOT be done, I'm assuming I need a JavaScript video player that can read an encrypted file and render it to an HTML 5 CANVAS as it's being decrypted.  However, that's more work.

Comment: It goes without saying that the VIDEO tag's src can be appended to incrementally (i. e. via a Timer event), but that may or may not work; there's no way to tell how much of the blob url the browser has exhausted at any time while rendering the video